# LaTeXmk and MusiXTeX. Or: adding commands to LaTeXmk workflow

Tags: latexmk, musixtex

I am working on a songbook in LaTeX using [MusiXTeX](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf). For that to work properly, I need to compile the document as follows:

```
pdflatex songbook
musixflx songbook
pdflatex songbook
```

Is there  a way to tell [LaTeXmk](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/support/latexmk/latexmk.pdf) to add `musixflx` to its workflow? If so, it would be easier to work on this songbook using [VimTeX](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex), which uses LaTeXmk.

LaTeXmk has options like `-bibtex`, but it doesn't have a dedicated option for MusiXTeX and I don't see in the manual if I can add arbitrary commands to the workflow.

Comment: from what i gather (havent carefully read the manual) one possibility would be to use the possibility to give the pdflatex command.. i.e. `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex %S; musixflx %S; pdflatex %S" `. But I havent tested that, its just what came to mind skimming over the manual

Comment: @Bort You also need to add a command to delete the `mx2` file before the first run of `pdflatex`.  With that change, your solution would work.  See my answer for an improvement.

Comment: @JohnCollins ah okay. turns out not only do I not know latexmk, I also do not know musixflx. your solution is way more sophisticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an appropriate insertion for the `latexmkrc` file.

```
$pdflatex = 'internal musixlatex %R %O %S';
push @generated_exts,"mx2";
push @generated_exts,"mx1";

sub musixlatex {
   my $root = shift;
   # Define root filename for the mx1 and mx2 files
   # Note that $aux_dir1 includes directory separator
   #      and it equals $out_dir1 if only the out_dir is set.
   my $mx = "$aux_dir1$root";
   my @args = @_;
   if ( $pass{$rule} <= 1 ) { 
      print "======= FIRST PASS: Deleting '$mx.mx2' =======\n";
      unlink "$mx.mx2"; 
      print "====   Generating '$mx.mx1' then '$mx.mx2' ===\n";
      my $ret = system( "pdflatex @args" );
      if ($ret) { return $ret; }
      $ret = system( "musixflx $mx" );
      if ($ret) { return $ret; }
   }
   return system( "pdflatex @args" );
}
```

The main thing is that it is necessary to delete the `.mx2` file before running `pdflatex` for the first time.  Then `musixflx` is run to generate a new `mx2` file, and then `pdflatex` again.

But sometimes more than two passes through `pdflatex` are needed to resolve cross references and the like.  So I've used a bit of trickery with an internal variable of `latexmk` so that the use of `musixflx` only happens on the first pass; this keeps the number of runs of `pdflatex` to the minimum.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but I'm getting `sh: 1: internal: not found`. Any idea what may cause that? I'm using Latexmk 4.43a (2015-02-05), so `internal` should be implemented.

Comment: It appears that `latexmk` has misinterpreted `internal` as a command name.  The code works for me when I copy and paste it from my answer.  It is possible something extra got inserted in your `latexmkrc` in front of the word "internal".  If you don't see anything relevant, could you send me your `latexmkrc` file off-line (to the address in the `latexmk` documentation), and I'll try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's odd. First: thanks, this is great, it's working from the command line. The result I gave before only happens when using VimTeX. I will look into it. Maybe it's an incompatibility, but that would then be their job. Maybe I've done something wrong in my configuration. In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: For reference, the VimTeX issue: https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/212