# Musixtex bars don't align in vertical

Tags: music, musixtex

I'm using musixetx to put music for a uni paper, and I need to put this as an example between text. The trouble is that bar and bar lines are not aligned. How can I align them?
Thank you so much!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}{4}}
    \setlines {1}{1}
    \setclefsymbol {1}\empty
    \startpiece
        \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ij \en \bar
        \Notes \qu i \ds \cu h \en \bar
        \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ij \en \bar
        \Notes \qu i \ds \cu h \en\alaligne
        \contpiece
        \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ii \en \bar
        \Notes \qu j \Dqbu jj \en \bar
        \Notes \qu {hj} \en \bar
        \Notes \qu i \en
    \Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define `\parindent` to `0pt` (and not use `\contpiece`).

To justify all lines, you must use the three pass system (p.4, [musixtex documentation](https://texdoc.org/pgk/musixtex)):

```sh
pdflatex doc.tex
musixflx doc.tex
pdflatex doc.tex
```

(note: the three pass system of `musixtex` can be automated by adding a `latexmkrc` file with the code from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260766/14500))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \parindent 0pt
  \instrumentnumber{1}
  \nobarnumbers
  \nostartrule
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac{2}{4}}
  \setlines {1}{1}
  \setclefsymbol {1}\empty
  \startpiece
  \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ij \en \bar
  \Notes \qu i \ds \cu h \en \bar
  \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ij \en \bar
  \Notes \qu i \ds \cu h \en\alaligne
  %\contpiece
  \Notes\qu i\Dqbu ii \en \bar
  \Notes \qu j \Dqbu jj \en \bar
  \Notes \qu {hj} \en \bar
  \Notes \qu i \en
  \Endpiece
  % \setlyrics{1}{Pas qua\spaceés a- vui}
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean, the end part of the staves, I want to align them. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Oh, right, how can I do it in Overleaf? I'm really new to this... I'm trying. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Eduard Add a `latexmkrc` file with the code from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260766/14500).

Comment: Thankyou so much!!! This works!